# Running aGoogle Workspace Add - ons over local HTTP endpoint

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk, google-workspace-add-ons

I tried to develop a workspace Add-On in a different language and I am completely stuck with this issue. it seems that my add-on does not call my local server endpoint. I get the following error message: "Content can't be loaded (see screenshot https://ibb.co/0VJHqJh)". Furthermore, I can clearly see on my server that my endpoints are not called.

Does Workspace addons support local http endpoint?

Currently, I have:

- a Fastapi server running at **http://127.0.0.1:8000** with multiple endpoints.
- each endpoint returns Json CardService. Here a basic endpoint example:

```py
@root_router.get('/homepage', response_class=JSONResponse)
async def homepage(event: object):
    print(event)
    # return json.dumps(BASIC_CARD)
    # return BASIC_CARD
    return renderAction


@root_router.post("/homepage2", response_class=JSONResponse)
async def homepage2(event: object):
    print(event)
    return renderAction
```

- my add-on is deployed and installed with the following deployments file

```json
{
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.addons.metadata.readonly"
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.currentonly"],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "My HTTP Add-on",
      "logoUrl": "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/googlematerialicons/markunread_mailbox/v6/black-24dp/1x/gm_markunread_mailbox_black_24dp.png",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/homepage"
      },
      "openLinkUrlPrefixes": ["http://127.0.0.1:8000/homepage"]
    },
    "gmail": {},
    "drive": {},
    "calendar": {}
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

No because the add-on run on Google servers and they have their own "local endpoint". In other words, `http://127.0.0.1` points to the server running the add-on not your machine.

Please bear in mind that the value of `homepageTrigger.runFunction` can't be an arbitrary URL, it should be the name of a function. Reference https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/homepage-trigger.

Resources

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons?hl=en#Common.FIELDS.openLinkUrlPrefixes

Comment: It makes complete sense. I had to use ngrok to connect my local dev server with my workspace add-ons to test the whole pipeline. and it seems to work like a charm now. Thank you for the feedback @Ruben.